# Solving an Equation System in SciPy

Tags: python, scipy, exponential

i am trying to fit an exponential curve through three given Points. But i get only very wrong results of fsolve or actual 0. I need this for my Bachelor Thesis so if anyone knows a better solution for the problem, it would be very kind to tell me this solution.

```
from numpy import *
from scipy.optimize import *

def myFunction(variables):
    x1 = 1
    y1 = 100
    x2 = 5
    y2 = 50
    x3 = 10
    y3 = 1
    (a,k,b) = variables

    y1 = a*exp(-x1*k)+b
    y2 = a*exp(-x2*k)+b
    y3 = a*exp(-x3*k)+b
    #0 = a*k**2 * exp(-x1+k)
    return ([a, k, b])

z = fsolve(myFunction,(1,0.1,5))
print(z)
```

this is my problem, i need to fit an e function through this 3 given points, and in addition the second derivation of the forumla should be 0

[image]

edit: 06.12.17
in some way i have now an improvement with a polynom, but does not really fit like it should. 
The second Maximum should not be there.. :D

```
from numpy import *
from scipy.optimize import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def myFunction(z):
    a = z[0]
    b = z[1]
    c = z[2]
    d = z[3]
    e = z[4]
    f = z[5]
    g = z[6]

    x = [0, 10 ,15 ,20 ,50 ,100]
    y = [10 ,90 ,100 ,90 ,50 ,10]
    s = [0, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0]

    F = empty((8))
    F[0] = a*x[0]**6 + b*x[0]**5 + c*x[0]**4 + d*x[0]**3 + e*x[0]**2 + f*x[0]**1 + g - y[0]
    F[1] = a*x[1]**6 + b*x[1]**5 + c*x[1]**4 + d*x[1]**3 + e*x[1]**2 + f*x[1]**1 + g - y[1]
    F[2] = a*x[2]**6 + b*x[2]**5 + c*x[2]**4 + d*x[2]**3 + e*x[2]**2 + f*x[2]**1 + g - y[2]
    F[3] = a*x[3]**6 + b*x[3]**5 + c*x[3]**4 + d*x[3]**3 + e*x[3]**2 + f*x[3]**1 + g - y[3]
    F[4] = a*x[4]**6 + b*x[4]**5 + c*x[4]**4 + d*x[4]**3 + e*x[4]**2 + f*x[4]**1 + g - y[4]
    F[5] = a*x[5]**6 + b*x[5]**5 + c*x[5]**4 + d*x[5]**3 + e*x[5]**2 + f*x[5]**1 + g - y[5]
    F[6] = 6*a*x[3]**5 + 5*b*x[3]**4 + 4*c*x[3]**3 + 3*d*x[3]**2 + 2*e*x[3]**1 + f - s[3]
    F[7] = 6*a*x[5]**5 + 5*b*x[5]**4 + 4*c*x[5]**3 + 3*d*x[5]**2 + 2*e*x[5]**1 + f - s[5]
    return F

zGuess = array([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1])
z = fsolve(myFunction,zGuess)
print(z)
x_axis = linspace(0,100,100)

y_axis = z[0]*x_axis**6 + z[1]*x_axis**5 + z[2]*x_axis**4 + z[3]*x_axis**3 + z[4]*x_axis**2 + z[5]*x_axis**1 + z[6]
plt.plot(x_axis, y_axis)
plt.show()
```

edit 07.12.17
the whole signal should look like the data of the second example. But the difficulty is in the part of the first example. My suggestion was to use 2 polynoms, but my prof would prefer an polynom x<20 and an e function x>20. The overlapping of both should also be very smooth.

Comment: One of the good ways is to use  least square method to fiind best answer with 0 degree of freedom, because u have three equation minus three unknowns

Comment: What are the points you have as data? in the first part, some samples, in the second, others, in addition, what is the model you have proposed: The exponential or the polynomial?

Comment: the whole signal should look like the data of the second example.  But the difficulty is in the part of the first example.  My suggestion was to use 2 polynoms,  but my prof would prefer an polynom x<20 and an e function x>20. The overlapping of both should also be very smooth.

Answer (score 1):

Well fsolve find the roots of a function, does not really do a non-linear fit. I must admit I don't actually quite get what you want to achieve with your code. If you want to do a nonlinear fit (since you are talking about exponential functions here) you may want to check my notebook here https://github.com/michelucci/Regression-with-Python/blob/master/(Non)%20linear%20fit%20in%20Python.ipynb that I hope can point you in the right direction. It contains first a part on linear regression and then a non-linear tutorial.

You can check `curve_fit()` python function in the scipy.optimize library. That should help you with what you want to do.

Let me know if that helps you.

You may also want to check this link to better understand what a non-linear fit is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_regression

Best, Umberto

Comment: i have added a picture of the problem, maybe this helps to understand. curve_fit would help, but the prof said he wants to have an e function if its possible.

Comment: Thanks. I think you simply need to do a fit of your data. Check the wikipedia article I linked. Is actually very easy to understand. I don't have time now but If I find time later I will try to put here some code you can try.